# jQuery UI autocomplete pulling json from database

Tags: json, jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying collect data from a database to in return populate the jQueryUI autocomplete field.

My ajax query that collects the data works fine as show below:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/devices/autocomplete",
    data: { keywords: keyword_string },
    cache: true,
    success: function(){

    }
});
```

This returns data in an json format - I basically want to 'merge' this function with my autocomplete function but not sure what i'm doing wrong.

```
        $("#tags").autocomplete({
          source: function(request, response){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/devices/autocomplete",
                    data: { keywords: keyword_string },
                    cache: true,
                    success: function(html){
                        //$("ul#results").html(html);
                    }
                });
          },
          minLength: 2,
          dataType: "json",
          cache: false,
          focus: function(event, ui) {
            return false;
          },
          select: function(event, ui) {
            this.value = ui.item.label;
            /* Do something with user_id */
            return false;
          }
        });
```

Can anyone explain how I pass the /devices/autocomplete URL to the autocomplete function & have this return the json data back to the autocomplete source?

Comment: see http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote, you can provide `url` directly in the autoComplete call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

provided the URL as explained by another user.